# ggplot percentage positive per factor class

Tags: r, ggplot2

Apologies for the noob question.
I have scoured the forum but have only come across counts as proportions per 100%  bar, or from all groups combined.

Can someone please help getting the following into a form so that only the % positive (Yes) are shown per "Parent" group a much neater fashion? ie a simple bar chart with the %yes shown and maybe with a % above each bar?

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)

test1<- data.frame(Class= c("yes","yes","NA","yes","NA","yes","yes","NA","yes","yes"), 
                   Parent= c("LN1","LN2","LN1","LN2","LN1","LN2","LN1","LN2","LN1","LN2"))

test1<- test1 %>% mutate_if(is.character, factor)

test1 %>% 
  mutate(Parent= fct_relevel(Parent, "LN1", "LN2")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Parent, fill= Class))+
  geom_bar(position = "fill",
          stat= "count") +
  geom_label(aes(y = ..prop..,
                 label = Class),
             position = "fill",
             stat = "Count")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
test1 %>% mutate(Parent= fct_relevel(Parent, "LN1", "LN2")) %>% 
  group_by(Parent) %>%
  count(Class) %>%
  mutate(pct = n/sum(n)) %>%
  filter(Class == "yes") %>%
  ggplot(aes(Parent, pct))+
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(pct)), color = "black", vjust = -1) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1))
```

Should get you this (use themes and other formatting as desired)

[image]

Comment: Excellent, glad it worked...to close out the question you should accept the answer. Should be a check mark you can click on, it'll turn green. Gets you good stackoverlfow karma.